# usage of array::data and array::front

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

Is there any difference between `& array::front` and `array::data`?

ex 1 :

```
const char* cstring = "Test String";
array<char, 12> carray;
std::memcpy(&carray.front(), cstring, 12);
```

ex 2:

```
const char* cstring = "Test String";
array<char, 12> carray;
std::memcpy(carray.data(), cstring, 12);
```

are the above two same? Or is there any special usage of `array::data`?

Comment: The second is easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is simply that [`front()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/front) returns a reference to the first element and [`data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data) returns a pointer to it. For zero-sized arrays, the former is undefined and the latter is unspecified. For non-zero-sized arrays, `data()` is exactly equivalent to `&front()`.

In this case, you should prefer `data()` simply because you need a pointer and that gives you a pointer.